# How to make text not to overflow box in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, text, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow

i am using Bootstrap 3, and i have a text within a col and when it's longer, it does not fit the div and overflows it in the width of the box. I have used different display styles, do a lot of search but without success.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://www.kungfunguyen.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Bootstrap-2-1-Is-the-Latest-Update-to-Twitter-s-Popular-Open-Source-Project.png">
                <div class="caption">
                  Very long text which oveflows the whole div in width.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example with thumbnail and caption, the same problem
http://jsfiddle.net/zqeLse5q/

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.caption{
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zqeLse5q/2/

Comment: Thanks U so much, i couldnt find this css stuff. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked. Accept the answer if it fixed your problem so other people don't waste time trying to answer the question also